# How to correctly (join if) MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT *
FROM `history`
WHERE `site_id` = '1'
    AND `user_id` = '1'
ORDER BY `date` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

In `history` table is field `child_user_id`. I need to check if in the `child_users` table this id exists and if so - replace it with `child_user_name` from  `child_users`, else set `user_name` from `users` table where `user_id = '1'`

Comment: don't get what you want... you should at least provide all table-specification + an EXACT description of what you want to do...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SET @useid =1;

SELECT case when c.id IS null then @useid 
       else (select user_name from  users where user_id=@useid) end 
FROM   history  h 
LEFT OUTER JOIN child_users c
ON     h.child_user_id=c.id
```

Comment: It isnt right because i need to select all from `history` table and change `user_id` reference to: if `child_user_id` with the same id in `child_users` exists change `user_id` to `child_user_name` from `child_users` or to `user_name` from `users` with same id.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
     SELECT * FROM `history`  LEFT OUTER JOIN  child_users 
      ON     history.child_user_id=child_user_id  WHERE `site_id` = '1'AND `user_id` = '1'
```